# How do I get the output of this circuit?

Tags: integrated-circuit, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I am trying to solve the truth table of the following circuit:

[image]

A, B, and C are the inputs. I tried getting the truth table by drawing the circuit in an online circuit simulator such as [falstad.com/circuit](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/) but it's not working, check it out:

[image]

What is the wrong in the circuit? Why isn't the output changing to H?

Is the truth table for the following circuit correct:

[image]

Comment: Output is just A.B.C from viewing it?

Comment: No i mean the truth table of this circuit. Can i add another post here and include the truth table for people to check if it's correct or not? or is it considered as solving a homework which will remove the post?

Comment: Add your truth table solution to your original question - put it as a section at the bottom of what you currently have. Make it clear it's an addition because you already have one answer.

Comment: done, check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this circuit.  Your circuit has bad connections.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frqyeA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Worked! Thanks !

Comment: @AhmadBenos Did it solve you problem?  Then click on the tick mark next to the answer please.

Comment: it did. got it!